How can I use nextjs with the Django
I started coding by using the python, When I surfed on internet, I get to know about Django. I used it very well and was easier to edit as this was generating pages dynamically. Now, I am Exploring about the nodejs and nextjs framework.
I think it is good combination of both Django and Nextjs so that I can get speed as well as security. I want to know how can I integrate nextjs into Django.

I will explain how to use django python for the backend while next js is used for the frontend.
You need to set up both next js and django projects in respective folders using npx create-next-app@latest and django-admin startproject.
In Django Project

Create the apps you would like to use and register them in settings.
Create the relevant models, schemas and views and point urls to the project urls.
Input some data that you want to show to your site in the database in django (by default is sqlite)
Ensure that your data can be seen in the django localhost 8000 and it is preferable to use JSON formats as this makes it easier in nextjs

Allowing Next Js to connect to Django
4. install django cors headers (https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/). Cors headers are used to expose allowed sites to your backend, in this case, next js, which runs on local host 3000 in development.
In settings.py,
4.1 Installed apps include corsheaders
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders",
    ...,
]

4.2 Include middle ware as follows:
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    ...,
]

4.3 Include cors allowed origins as follows
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://example.com", #use this in production to point to live website
    "https://sub.example.com", #use this in production
    "http://localhost:3000", #default next js on localhost, otherwise 3001
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000", #still next js development
]

Next JS Project.
Let us try to get some data from django backend and show up in localhost 3000

For example in page.js , page.jsx or page.tsx (the homepage default)



"use client";
    export default function Home() {
      async function getDjangoAPIData() {
        const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/hello");
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
      }
      async function handleClick() {
        await getDjangoAPIData();
      }
      return (
        <main>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Lookup data</button>
        </main>
      );
    }



Explanation as follows:
-We declare use client as this is a client action of button pressing
-The fetch api is an asynchronous function we are using to collect data.
-We point to our django project in the link as well as the django url where our json data is to be got from.
-Asynchronous functions need to be await as data is retrieved in JSON and log the data on console.
-The button labeled "Lookup Data" triggers the action of getting data
Thank you. In the example, I am using Ninja Api but you may use Fast Api or Django Rest Framework

Welcome, Kelly! The answer looks solid and detailed. Nice first contribution!

you are welcome. Did it work? you should consider using server actions to fetch as well

just wanted to can we use server side rendering while routing pages from django backend and next js as front end or is there better way to use ssr i already have front end using bootstrap html css js just wanted to change site for seo

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If this is a question, please open an specific topic for it. People here will be pleasured to try to help you. Please, be clear and objective, but try to explain in details what you have in mind/what you have done so far.

If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - From Review

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
